# Pixate Freestyle library alternatives?

Tags: android, ios, css, pixate

We are using [Pixate Freestyle](https://github.com/Pixate/pixate-freestyle-ios) for multiple projects right now, but it looks like this library is no longer being developed.

Its functionality on Android is questionable (ex. custom fonts not working yet), and we can't really spend our time fixing it, therefore we are looking for a similar library, which allows you to style elements with CSS, working both for iOS and Android.

Do you guys know of any similar libraries?